# Does object[] boxes or not

Tags: c#, boxing, unboxing

Tryin to understand boxing and unboxing I came up with a question.

What happens on the `object obj = arr` line in this example?

```
object[] arr = new object[] {1, 2};
object obj = arr;
```

Is there any boxing happening on the second line?

Comment: No, since `arr` is a reference type.

Comment: No; `arr` is an array (`T[]`) which is *reference* type (`class`)

Comment: Well, `object[]` is an array of `object`. `1` and `2` are certainly value-types that are then implicitely converted to `object`. Thus there is boxing when putting the numbers into array, not when referencing the array-instance via another variable.

Comment: @PatrickHofman If you squint hard enough then `The Array itself is already a reference type, there is no boxing on the array itself.` is technically accurate and _could_ be applicable to this situation. But again - I think it is a poor choice of duplicate. _A poor choice since it only makes sense to those who know the answer to the question to start with - which **clearly the OP doesn't**._

Comment: @Belurd If you are not sure, if there is boxing/unboxing happening or not, you can always create such simple examples like this one and disassemble with ILDasm.exe, to see what's really happening.

Comment: Then you assume someone understands the syntax reading the IL. @SeM

Comment: @PatrickHofman well, yes, but you can always figure out  for example boxing/unboxing parts, and not learn whole syntax if you are not interested.

Answer (score 4):

In the first line:

```
object[] arr = new object[] {1, 2};
```

The 1 and 2 int literals are boxed, since the array is an array of `object`.

However, in the second line, no boxing occurs since an array is a reference type.

```
object obj = arr;
```

Comment: That is the definitive answer, afaik It is a "yes but no" case :)

Comment: Only possible improovement might be to disolve that syntax sugar of the array initializer into the actuall code, to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Since an [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types), there is no boxing or unboxing going on in your second line.